# How to have a page curl effect between activities on android using Xamarin C#?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, page-curl

I need to have this effect of page curling in my aplication but i can only find java examples like here :

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mP_AlvJqSLQ

Or ehre :

https://code.google.com/p/android-page-curl/

But i cant find anything for c#, does someone knows how to do that in c#??

Comment: Hi, I hope you solved it. Please share.

Comment: Unfortunally i didn't :/